# is the complexity of an algorithm connected to the "classification" of a optimization problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization

I wonder if the complexity is connected to an optimization problem. In general but also specifically e.g. when having a look at $ O(n^2) $. Does this just describe the complexity in general or does it also mean does the underlying algorithm has to be a nonlinear optimization problem? Or is it also valid for linear tasks?

In simple words: Can a nonlinear task be solved in $ O(n) $?

Comment: What is a "nonlinear task"?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question at all. Saying that the running time is $O(n^2)$ just means that there's a constant $k$ such that, for all large enough inputs, the algorithm requires at most $kn^2$ steps to complete. That's all. Maybe it only takes $k\log n$ steps. (I have at most a million dollars in the bank; maybe I only have \$100.)

Comment: $ O(n^2) $ is a kind of nonlinear, right? While $ O(n) $ increases linearly with n, $ O(n^2) $ does not. I just would like to know if these terms are somehow related to the (non-)linearity of the task to perform/solve.

Comment: You can find arbitrary bad algorithms for problems that are solvable in linear time. The difficulty of a problem is just a lower bound on how good (i.e. fast) an algorithm might perform on an instance of that problem.